# Where to put debug flag in Xcode4?

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I am curious about where to put the debug flag in Xcode4. Currently I have [LLVM compiler 2.0 Preprocessing] > [Preprocessing Macros] > [debug] set to DEBUG=1. Is this the right place (it seems to work), or can this now be added to the new scheme system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's where I've been putting it and so far it's worked fine for me.